# How to get EF6 to work with DB2 in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: db2, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2017

I've read numerous articles and posts here about getting Entity Framework to work with DB2 but all of them reference prior versions of Visual Studio.  When I repeat the steps outlined (too many to remember at this point), I still do not have DB2 in the data providers list.

Has anyone gotten this to work in VS17 and, if so, can you walk me through what you did?

Answer (score 0):

For registering IBM Database Add-Ins for Visual Studio 17, Visual Studio 2015 or earlier supported versions needs to be installed on the machine.

Steps:

- Download and install IBM Data Server Driver Package
- Download and install IBM Database Add-Ins for Visual Studio.
- After successful installation of IBM Database Add-Ins, choose Start -> IBM Database Add-Ins for Visual Studio ->Register IBM Database Add-Ins.

This link has listed the steps needed for the add-in installation
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/96960515-2ea1-4391-8170-b0515d08e4da/entry/VSAIFORVS2017?lang=en

Note: Make sure to download same version and fix pack of DS Driver and VS IBM Database Add-In. I downloaded v11.1.3fp3 version for both installations and it's working for me.